# How can I make a div holding smaller divs to hold 3 on one line and then go on to the next line?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent div which I am filling with divs of a certain size, whenever I get to 3 divs (and at the same time the parent's div width is filled with those smaller divs within) I want to get on the next line/row. How can I do that? I am generating the divs with JavaScript.

Basically what I want is to add elements to that parent div horizontally and when there is no more space on the sepcific line to move to the bottom one and add elements there.

Comment: Post a [mcve] showing us what you have please

Comment: maintaining the level of generality of the question: `display: flex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with [a CSS grid with auto-placment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Auto-placement_in_CSS_Grid_Layout):

```js
function addDiv() {
  const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.classList.add('grid-div');
  const myGrid = document.querySelector('.my-grid');
  myGrid.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

```css
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
</div>

<button onclick="addDiv()">Add DIV</button>
```